# Jmeter - run JDBC request queries for all the values from CSB file

Tags: jmeter

My JMeter test plan is set up this way :

Test Plan

```
  JDBC Connection Configuration

  Thread Group
    
            CSV Data Set Config

            Transaction Controller 1

                              Sampler 1
                              Sampler 2
             
            Transaction Controller 2

                               Sampler 3
                               Sampler 4

             JDBC Request
```

So as part of the test plan data from the CSV file is used in the various samplers to create data and finally the created data must be deleted before the next test is executed.
JDBC request towards the end has various delete queries in which the data from the CSV file is used. Now my requirement is that if the test is executed for say 50 threads then will all the queries in the JDBC request be executed 50 times each. ? If not what changes do I need to implement in order to ensure that the JDBC request is executed for each input data from CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you did configure [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), especially "Sharing Mode" setting.

By default (`All threads`) - JMeter will pick the next line from the CSV file on each iteration of each thread.

If you want each thread to read the file individually - change it to `Current thread`

More information: [CSV Data Set Config in Sharing Mode - Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config)